# List CSV Files in a folder SQL using xp_dirTree

Tags: sql-server

I have a folder with lots of CSV files with the same format and am trying to import them all into a single table in Microsoft SQL Server (17.5). However the `xp_dirTree` seems to be unable to pick up the CSVs in the folder. Below is the code I am using:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_dirTree 'C:\test\', 1, 1;
```

and it returns nothing, even though I have put two CSV files into the test folder. If I run below:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_dirTree 'C:\', 1, 1;
```

I get a list of all folders in my C drive, so it just seems to be unable to pick up CSVs

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: it is version 17.5

Comment: There is no such version. Please share outcome of the following statement: `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: Sorry it is Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: SQL Server 2017 introduced DMVs that are much better than the old `xp_dirTree` extended stored procedure. That was the reason for my question about the version.

Answer (score -1):

```
>

 > enter code here
    > 
    > USE TestData 
 GO 
 CREATE TABLE CSVTest 
( ID INT, 
 FirstName VARCHAR(40),
  LastName VARCHAR(40),
  BirthDate SMALLDATETIME)  
GO
  Create CSV file in
    > drive C: with name csvtest.txt with following content. The location of
    > the file is C:\csvtest.txt  1,James,Smith,19750101 2,Meggie,Smith,19790122 3,Robert,Smith,20071101 4,Alex,Smith,20040202
    > 
    
 INSERT CSVTest FROM ‘c:\csvtest.txt’ WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =
    > ‘,’, ROWTERMINATOR = ‘\n’ )  
GO
```